# wondering why there is no space in front of the output(.join()) build in fnc

Tags: python, python-2.7

the code is very simple

```
chrs = chr(int(ord('A')+random.random()*26))
filledline = ''.join(5 * [chrs])+'\n'
```

why there isnot any space in front of the chrs?

can you please how .join fnc really work.

Comment: Why *would* there be a space?  You're joining them together with an empty string.

Comment: Why do `int(someInt + random.random() * 26)` when you could just do `someInt + random.randrange(26)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"*".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Outputs

```
"a*b*c"
```

Accordingly

```
"".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Outputs

```
"abc"
```

In order to spaces *in front* of the string, you have to do some concatenation:

```
"   " + "".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Outputs

```
"   abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The join method joins the values of the passed list into a string with the join separator specified at the start. In case of empty `''`, join separator just the values of the list into a string without any separator.

Try the method with `','.join()` and you will get a fair idea about it.

```
a = ["Hello","world!"]
print ', '.join(a)
```

output

`Hello, world!`

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I tried several times, ' '.join()mains use whatever inside ' 'to split the list.

sry for  my stupid question.